# Using a C extern function inside a C++ file: Linking issues with Makefile

Tags: c++, c, linker, makefile

I have an issue. I have defined in C file, read-line.c, a function print, like this:

```
void history_print(void)
{
    /* some stuff */
}
```

In a C++ file, command.cc, I have the following:

```
extern "C" void history_print(void);
```

and then I simply call history_print().

```
#Use GNU compiler
cc = gcc -g
CC = g++ -g   

all: shell

tty-raw-mode.o: tty-raw-mode.c
    gcc -c tty-raw-mode.c

read-line.o: read-line.c
    gcc -c read-line.c

lex.yy.o: shell.l
    lex shell.l
    $(cc) -c lex.yy.c

y.tab.o: shell.y
    yacc -d shell.y
    $(CC) -c y.tab.c

command.o: command.cc
    $(CC) -c command.cc

shell: y.tab.o lex.yy.o tty-raw-mode.o read-line.o command.o
    $(CC) -o shell lex.yy.o y.tab.o tty-raw-mode.o read-line.o command.o -ll -lgen
```

I have an issue when it comes to linking, in my Makefile, for the rule output:

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
history_print                       command.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to shell
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shell'
```

Output of -v option flag for make:

```
yacc -d shell.y
g++ -g -v -c y.tab.c
Reading specs from /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../sources/gcc-3.4.6/configure --prefix=/opt/csw/gcc3 --with-local-    prefix=/opt/csw --without-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --without-gnu-ld     --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --enable-threads=posix --enable-shared --enable-multilib     --enable-nls --with-included-gettext --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/csw --with-x --enable-    java-awt=xlib --enable-languages=all
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6
 /opt/csw/gcc3/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v y.tab.c -quiet     -dumpbase y.tab.c -mcpu=v7 -auxbase y.tab -g -version -o /var/tmp//ccCi8vXj.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../..    /../../sparc-sun-solaris2.8/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/sparc-    sun-solaris2.8
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/backward
 /opt/csw/include
 /opt/csw/gcc3/include
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ version 3.4.6 (sparc-sun-solaris2.8)
        compiled by GNU C version 3.4.6.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
 /usr/ccs/bin/as -V -Qy -s -xarch=v8 -o y.tab.o /var/tmp//ccCi8vXj.s
/usr/ccs/bin/as: SunOS 5.10 118683-05 Patch 04/30/2010
lex shell.l
gcc -g -c lex.yy.c
gcc -c tty-raw-mode.c
gcc -c read-line.c
g++ -g -v -c command.cc
Reading specs from /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../sources/gcc-3.4.6/configure --prefix=/opt/csw/gcc3 --with-local-    prefix=/opt/csw --without-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --enable-threads=posix --enable-shared --enable-multilib --enable-nls --with-included-gettext --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/csw --with-x --enable-    java-awt=xlib --enable-languages=all
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6
 /opt/csw/gcc3/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/cc1plus -quiet -v command.cc -quiet -dumpbase command.cc -mcpu=v7 -auxbase command -g -version -o /var/tmp//cckVWlC7.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../sparc-sun-solaris2.8/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/sparc-sun-solaris2.8
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../../../include/c++/3.4.6/backward
 /opt/csw/include
 /opt/csw/gcc3/include
 /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ version 3.4.6 (sparc-sun-solaris2.8)
        compiled by GNU C version 3.4.6.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
 /usr/ccs/bin/as -V -Qy -s -xarch=v8 -o command.o /var/tmp//cckVWlC7.s
/usr/ccs/bin/as: SunOS 5.10 118683-05 Patch 04/30/2010
g++ -g -v -o shell lex.yy.o y.tab.o tty-raw-mode.o read-line.o command.o -ll -lgen
Reading specs from /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../sources/gcc-3.4.6/configure --prefix=/opt/csw/gcc3 --with-local-    prefix=/opt/csw --without-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --enable-threads=posix --enable-shared --enable-multilib --enable-nls --with-included-gettext --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/csw --with-x --enable-    java-awt=xlib --enable-languages=all
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6
 /opt/csw/gcc3/libexec/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/collect2 -V -R /opt/csw/lib -Y P,/opt/csw/lib:/usr/ccs/lib:/usr/lib -Qy -o shell /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/crt1.o /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/crti.o     /usr/ccs/lib/values-Xa.o /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/crtbegin.o -L/opt    /csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6 -L/usr/ccs/bin -L/usr/ccs/lib -L/opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/../../.. lex.yy.o y.tab.o tty-raw-mode.o read-line.o command.o -ll -lgen -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/crtend.o /opt/csw/gcc3/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.8/3.4.6/crtn.o
ld: Software Generation Utilities - Solaris Link Editors: 5.10-1.497
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
history_print                       command.o
ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors. No output written to shell
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `shell'
```

I guess the issue is due to linking, and it has to do with the Makefile, but I am not sure how to fix. Could anyone please help me?

Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

Jary

Comment: May I recommend strongly against `CC = g++`. CC should be the c compiler, and you should use CXX (GNU make) or CPP for the c++ compiler. Yes there are tutorials on the web that suggest using CC for the c++ compiler, but they generally do so in a c++ *only* context. As you have both language you *need* to differentiate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will change for CXX, thanks!

Comment: `CPP` is for the C preprocessor.

Comment: Just out of interest, what happens if you use the GNU linker instead of the Solaris one?

Comment: Sorry I am still clunky with Makefile. How do I precise that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile needs a linking rule rather than the separate compilation rules:

```
CC  = gcc -g
CPP = g++ -g

program: a.o b.o
    ${CPP} -o $@ a.o b.o
```

Make already knows how to convert source into object files - you don't need to retrain it.

Comment: Well actually, I have more linking rules, I just displayed the ones that were producing an issue at this point.

Comment: OK - then don't compile a.c with the C++ compiler; it is, after all, C source, not C++ source.  And, despite the plethora of C/C++ questions on SO, they are separate (though related) languages.  This question actually **would be** correctly tagged with C and C++ since it involves both languages, albeit in separate source files.

Comment: I think I actually have what you propose Jonathan. Please check the bottom of my initial post, I posted the whole makefile. In output, it seems that what you are telling me is what I am doing, isn't it?

Comment: @Jary: what you've got in the whole makefile is different from what you originally posted - which still appears at the top.  The original `b.o` rule should not be invoking the loader - I'm not wholly convinced that you posted the correct makefile fragment.  Your lex and yacc rules are a little simplistic too - lending further credence to 'what we see is not quite what you execute'.  Your whole makefile looks OK.

Comment: @Jary: Please note as D McKee points out that CC is reserved by POSIX make for the C compiler; it should not be used for the C++ compiler.  Either CXX or CPP is recommended for the C++ compiler.

Comment: Sorry when I first posted the makefile, I wanted to post only what I thought was necessary. What I posted bellow is what I have, and I get the symbol error when it tries to execute output, giving me the undefined symbol print in b.o. I am sorry, it's not actually the b.o rule that it stops at, it's at the output rule, that is my mistake, I see I simplified too much and removed the real problem.

Comment: I've updated my post, hopefully the issue becomes more clear now. The error is the same but it actually happen for output. The Makefile that I now have in my initial post was identical before I added the extern function call, it only started complaining after that call was added.

Comment: @Jary: remove a.o and rebuild.  I think it got compiled once with the C++ compiler and therefore defines the C++ link-safe name for `print()` instead of the undecorated C name.  Alternatively, on Linux or Unix machines, use `nm -g a.o` to see what function is defined in `a.o`; my guess is that the name is not `print`!

Comment: To avoid confusion, I just renamed print to printTest. I removed all the .o files, and recompiled. I still get the error. After nm - g a.o I get: [23]    |        64|     228|FUNC |GLOB |0    |5      |printTest; but I still have the undefined error, the symbol is now printTest though. Thanks.

Comment: @Jary: it looks like you're using Solaris?  Very weird...the `nm` says the symbol is there, but the rest of the link says it is not.  Clutching at straws: there's no other error message - nothing about wrong architecture or anything?  More plausibly: what does 'nm -g b.o | grep printTest' give you - a decorated or an undecorated name?  This should be an UNDEF entry - the reference to `printTest()`.

Comment: Yes I am using Solaris. Nothing about wrong architecture, just undefined symbol, ld: fatal: Symbol referencing errors., collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target. For the nm -g b.o, I get [25]    |         0|       0|NOTY |GLOB |0    |UNDEF  |printTest; apparently it's UNDEF.

Comment: @Jary: mysteriouser and mysteriouser...are the file names really single letters, or are you mapping them for the purposes of the question?  It's behaving as if `a.o` is not handled by the linker, or as if it is pulling the file from somewhere other than where you expect.  Since you're using G++/GCC, can you trace the commands executed with the '-v' option: `make CPP='g++ -g -v'`.  The output will be verbose - probably won't fit in a comment, so amend the question.

Comment: I do not change the order of the files, but I did rename them, there are more than one character each, there's just a bit cumbersome. I am posting the output in the original command.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I have actually completely updated the Makefile to reflect what I actually have. It will make reading the output easier for you I think. Now you have exactly what I get, so no renaming of files or function calls.

Comment: @Jary: thanks.  I suppose history_print() is defined in read-line.c?  I don't see what is going on yet (it all looks kosher) - and it is 5 past bedtime for me.  I'll take another look in the morning.  I do have a Solaris 10 SPARC with GCC 3.4.6 still on it.  If you wanted to send me the code and makefile in a gzipped tar file (see my profile for email address), I might be able to reproduce the issue, or resolve it.  But I won't be looking for 7 hours or so now.

Comment: history_print is defined in read-line.c. I do not mind sending you the code. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jary, I think your linker may be somehow broken. `nm` on both files agree that the function is called `printTest`, defined in a.o with a reference in b.o yet the linker refuses to find it. Try to test with GNU's own linker if available and/or put command.o at the start of the list (that shouldn't matter but, once we get into suspect tools mode, we need to check everything).

Comment: @Jary: with the code on hand, I can see a 'late night thinko' - you call `history_print()` but you define `print_history()`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: the name mapping used in the early revisions of the question hid the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan! It was a really stupid error: I did not type the function name correctly. I apologize for that!

Answer (score 6):

It's because you're recompiling the `a.c` file with `g++` and that doesn't have an `extern C` wrapper around the function definition. Hence the name will undergo C++ mangling and there will be no `print` in the `a.o` object file.

However, `b.cc` will think that `print` is a C name (since it *has* the `extern C`) so it will go looking for the unmangled version.

Either put `extern C` around the definition in `a.c` (which probably makes that unusable with a regular C compiler, so keep that in mind) or change your `g++` command to use `a.o` (which has the unmangled name by virtue of the fact it was done with the C compiler) instead of `a.c`.

---

In fact, that won't work because you're not invoking the linker in the `g++` command. I'm not even sure *why* you're trying to include `a.o` into `b.o`. Probably the best time to do that is at link time to create an `ab` executable, not compile time, something like:

```
CC = g++ -g

a.o: a.c
    gcc -o a.o -c a.c

b.o: b.cc
    $(CC) -o b.o -c b.cc

ab: a.o b.o
    $(CC) -o ab a.o b.o
```

---

*Update:* Breaking it down to the simplest test case so you can see what I mean:

```
a.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    void print(void) {
        printf ("7\n");
    }

b.cc:
    extern "C" void print(void);
    int main(void) {
        print();
        return 0;
    }

Makefile:
    output: a.o b.o Makefile
        g++ -o output a.o b.o

    a.o: a.c Makefile
        gcc -o a.o -c a.c

    b.o: b.cc Makefile
        g++ -o b.o -c b.cc
```

Then running make and the program:

```
pax> make
gcc -o a.o -c a.c
g++ -o b.o -c b.cc
g++ -o output a.o b.o

pax> ./output
7
```

If you change the compilation of `a.c` to use `g++`, that gives you your original error where it cannot find `print`:

```
pax> make
g++ -o a.o -c a.c
g++ -o b.o -c b.cc
g++ -o output a.o b.o
b.o:b.cc:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `_print'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [output] Error 1
```

Now it appears that your final Makefile is correct. It compiles `a.c` with the C compiler so that the name mangling does not take place. My advice is to clean everything (remove all the `*.o` files) and run `make` again, then post the output here at the bottom of your question.

It may be that some of the files are older ones which is why you should delete *all* the object files before running `make`.

Comment: Replacing a.c by a.o, I get the same error, but with a warning before: g++: a.o: linker input file unused because linking not done. How can I please fix this?

Comment: Using a.o doesn't help because that is a compilation-to-object command, not a linking command.

Comment: When using -o rather than -c, I get the following: g++: no input files
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `a.o'

Comment: I posted a more complete code, I hope you can help me. Sorry I'm having such issues with Makefile.

Comment: @Jary, you don't use `-o` _instead_ of `-c`, you use it _in addition to_. I put that in since I like to always explicitly set the output file since many linkers invariably create an `a.out` file instead of something more intelligently named. And I can't see anything immediately wrong with your latest update. What problem are you having now?

Comment: Thank you. I have added the extra -o as you mentioned and it worked but the error is still here. The undefined symbol error still shows up.

Comment: most probably your `make` command knows about which is are the C and C++ compilers and about naming conventions for C and C++ filenames. It will just do the right thing if you don't give *rules*. Just giving the dependencies themselves should suffice. Then remove all .o files, and try again.

Comment: I tried your solution but that does not work. It tries to use g++ for .c files and complains about unknown functions.

Comment: @Jary, see the further update. Please clean up your object files then run `make` and post the output here (at the bottom of your question).